docker-compose fails with error "urllib3.exceptions.URLSchemeUnknown: Not supported URL scheme http+docker"
I'm currently working on a .NETcore project and I've been utilizing docker-compose to build the project. This setup has been working well in the past, but I've recently encountered some errors which I'm struggling to resolve.
When I execute the docker-compose build command, I receive the following errors:
"urllib3.exceptions.URLSchemeUnknown: Not supported URL scheme http+docker"
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
"docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: Not supported URL scheme http+docker"

Can someone help fix this . Thanks
I use following tool version:
docker --version
Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41
docker-compose pinned to 6.1.3 to continue using compose V1 for my project.
To fix this, I have tried different versions of these tools and it didn't help.

Do you have a $DOCKER_HOST environment variable set; where does an http+docker URL come from?  Is there any reason to not use the plugin-based Compose v2?

Resolution is in this link https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/3256.
Pinning requests version to 2.31.0 resolved the issue.

pip install requests==2.31.0 is one way to do this. Feel free to edit it into the answer if you want.
